# QIODevice::read : device not open

Tags: json, qt, qfile

I finally found a path file QFile would accept using QFile.exist() and a healthy dose of trial and error.

I want to know why the following works:

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonDocument>

QString path = QDir::currentPath();     // Get current dir
path.append("/noteLibrary.json");

QFile file(path);           // Give QFile current dir + path to file
if (!file.exists()) {       // Check to see if QFile found the file at given file_path
    qDebug() << "NO FILE HERE";
}
qDebug() << path;           // See what path was finally successful
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);      // Continue parsing document to confirm everything else is functioning normally.
QByteArray rawData = file.readAll();

// Parse document
QJsonDocument doc(QJsonDocument::fromJson(rawData));

// Get JSON object
QJsonObject json = doc.object();

// Access properties
qDebug() << json["die"].toString();     // Should output "280C4"
```

Successful output:

```
"/home/pi/noteLibrary.json"
"280C4"
```

But the following does NOT work:

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonDocument>

QFile file("/home/pi/noteLibrary.json");           // Give QFile current dir + path to file
if (!file.exists()) {       // Check to see if QFile found the file at given file_path
    qDebug() << "NO FILE HERE";
}

//qDebug() << path;           // See what path was finally successful
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);      // Continue parsing document to confirm everything else is functioning normally.
QByteArray rawData = file.readAll();

// Parse document
QJsonDocument doc(QJsonDocument::fromJson(rawData));

// Get JSON object
QJsonObject json = doc.object();

// Access properties
qDebug() << json["die"].toString();     // Should output "280C4"
```

Error output:

```
NO FILE HERE
QIODevice::read (QFile, "/home/pi/Desktop/noteLibrary.json"): device not open
""
```

Why would QFile treat these differently? Is this a QString format issue? Or is the fact that I'm deploying this remotely to a Raspberry Pi 3 possibly to blame?

Comment: The second piece of code can't do this output because of `path` variable is not declared there. Also the real path that you give to `QFile` is `/home/pi/Desktop/noteLibrary.json` and not `/home/pi/noteLibrary.json`. Check this up, please.

Comment: Wow. I must have copy/pasted the wrong output from one of the last 8 tries to make this work. Sorry for wasting your time on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of what was wrong with my code above, with the below code giving QFile the absolute path does work equally to creating a QString with currentPath(). I must have had something else wrong, my mistake!

*noteLibrary.json*

```
{"note": [{
             "profile": "C4",
             "die": "280C4",
             "pressure": 800,
             "position": 10000
         },
         {
             "profile": "CC4",
             "die": "2280C4",
             "pressure": 8800,
             "position": 110000
         }

    ],
    "test": {
        "profile": "CCC4",
        "die": "22280C4",
        "pressure": 88800,
        "position": 1110000
    }
}
```

*main.cpp* excerpt

```
    QFile file("/home/pi/noteLibrary.json");
    if (!file.exists()) qDebug() << "NO FILE FOUND";
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QByteArray rawData = file.readAll();
    QJsonDocument doc(QJsonDocument::fromJson(rawData));    // Parse document
    QJsonObject jObj = doc.object();    // Get JSON object
    qDebug() << jObj["test"];
```

Application Output

```
QJsonValue(object,QJsonObject({"die":"22280C4","position":1110000,"pressure":88800,"profile":"CCC4"}))
```

Seems odd that it displays property values in alphabetical order, not the order listed in the document.